# restoring backed up thunderbird files

Tags: backup, thunderbird, restore

How can I restore my backed up thunderbird files after format? Do I just copy the files back where thunderbird store these files? Or must I use import in thunderbird? What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if it's the best way, but this is what I do:

- Run Thunderbird up once on the new system (but don't create any mailboxes). This will create a directory in `~/.thunderbird` with a generated hash and ".default" appended to the end.
- Extract the backup into the directory.
- Restart Thunderbird. It should find all the restored mailboxes and all the previous settings.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I didn't zip the folder(s) I backed up, will it make difference if I just copy it back?

Comment: I don't think so, as long as the structure is the same (everything in the right spot where Thunderbird expects it to be).

Comment: Thanks, I just copied back and opened Thunderbird with all the accounts and mail back to where it belong.